# Javascript module pattern: How to inject/create/extend methods/plugin to our own library?

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

Im new to javascript. Sorry if there is anything wrong with my question.

How to inject/create/extend methods or plugins to our own library?
here is "yourlib.js"

```
var Yourlib = (function() {
    // privt. var
    var selectedEl = {}

    // some privt. funct
    function something() {

    }

    return {
        getById : function() {

        },
        setColor : function() {

        }
    }
}());
```

And below is your "plugin.js"

```
/*
How to create the plugin pattern?
Example: I want to create/inject a method/plugin named "setHeight" .
So, i can call it later, like this: Yourlib.getById('an-id').setHeight(value);
How is the pattern?
*/
```

Comment: I think this question belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that your function returns an object with two methods. You can directly add properties to it:

```
Yourlib.setHeight = function (val) {
    // logic for setting the height
};
```

Comment: WOw.. so simple! So, which should i do, Yourlib.setHeight = function(va) { }; or use Yourlib.prototype.setHeight??

Comment: @JaheJS take a look at my comment for prototype under the other answer

Comment: @JaheJS: Is `Yourlib` a constructor function with a `prototype` property? The one you posted in your question is not.

Comment: @Konstantin D - Infragistics : Thank you for all your help. I still wonder, should we add Yourlib.prototype = {} first or not (and just go with this-> Yourlib.setHeight=funct...)

Comment: Don't use .prototype. You are having a single instance and not a function which you instantiate into an object with new. prototype would just be a property to that object. If you try it out you will see.

Answer (score 9):

You need to return `this` within your functions to make them chainable. The example code below shows how to extend your module to allow chained calls and add new functions if needed.

```js
var Yourlib = (function() {

  // privt. var
  var selectedEl = {}

  // some privt. funct
  function something() {


  }

  return {

    setColor: function(newcolor) {

      var obj = document.getElementById('colorbox1');
      obj.style.background = newcolor;

    }
  }

}());

// call the original module sub-function
Yourlib.setColor('blue');

/**
 * Extend the module again to allow chaining.
 * Chainable functions return "this"
 */
var Yourlib = (function(object) {

  // private variable to store id of a box
  var box = '';

  object.getById = function(id) {

    box = document.getElementById(id);
    return this;
  };

  object.setColor = function(newcolor) {

    box.style.background = newcolor;
    return this;

  };

  object.setAnotherColor = function(newcolor) {

    var box = document.getElementById('colorbox4');
    box.style.background = newcolor;

  };

  return object; // return the extended object

}(Yourlib)); // original module passed in as an object to be extended


// example of a chained function call 
Yourlib.getById('colorbox2').setColor('purple');

// same functions without chained call
Yourlib.getById('colorbox3')
Yourlib.setColor('green');

// new function within extended module
Yourlib.setAnotherColor('orange');
```

```css
.colorbox {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: #000;
  border: #000 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<strong>module sub-function</strong>
<br />Yourlib.setColor('blue');
<br />
<div id="colorbox1" class="colorbox"></div>

<strong>chained function calls</strong>
<br />Yourlib.getById('colorbox2').setColor('purple');
<br />
<div id="colorbox2" class="colorbox"></div>

<strong>functions called without chaining</strong> 
<br />Yourlib.getById('colorbox3')
<br />Yourlib.setColor('green');
<br />
<div id="colorbox3" class="colorbox"></div>

<strong>new function added to extended module</strong>
<br />Yourlib.setAnotherColor('orange');
<br />
<div id="colorbox4" class="colorbox"></div>
```

For further reference you may also read [JavaScript Module Pattern in Depth](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
var Module = (function(){
 var set = {}
 set.show = function(){
   alert('Module method')
 }
 return set
})()
```

So now I will extend current Module.

```
var Ext = (function(Module){

 Module.get = function(){
   Module.show()
 }

 return Module

})(Module)
```

Now I can do this:

```
Module.get()
Ext.get()
```